# How can I create a trigger for when a lead has activity?

Tags: trigger, leads, activities

When a lead has activity and the lead status is new, that it prompts the user to change to lead status to open.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to prompt the user rather than just set the value automatically?

Comment: We have sales users that make calls and email activities on leads, but they don't reset the lead status to 'open'. I don't think we would want it automatic because they may reach a point where they want the status to reflect another level such as nurture.

Comment: The outline of one solution is to create a small VF page that conditionally renders an apex:pageMessage when {!Lead.tasks.size} is not null and {!Lead.status = 'New'}.  Add the VF page into the standard page layout. To test the size of the list for non null without using a controller extension, see LaceySnr: http://www.laceysnr.com/2013/02/two-visualforce-methods-for-conditional.html

Comment: @Crop, I had an idea similar to yours using a validation rule on Activities for Leads. The syntax may not be exactly correct, but something along the lines of `AND (IF($ObjectType.Leads.Fields.Status = "new", ))`. If it evaluates to true, an error message would be presented telling the user to update the Status of the Lead. It seems this needs to act on Activities/Tasks as opposed to Leads when it's "triggered".

Comment: My original (now discarded) idea was a soft alert on Lead using a formula field - `if (ispickval(status,'new') && NOT(ISBLANK(lastActivityDate)),'Pls change lead status to "open",null)` - but `LastActivityDate` is set only on closed activities so the formula will miss open activities